# Cannot change site address or url in WP settings

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Both options are grayed out and I've been trying to figure it out and can't find the right answer. I've tried this article: https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/ still nothing.
I'm using Elementor as my website builder if that matters. I just want it to be my website name instead of an ip address.

Answer (score 1):

First you should check the wp-config.php file of your Wordpress installation. You probably have something like this `define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');` there.
Once you remove that the fields shouldn't be grayed out anymore.
If that doesn't work maybe you are using something like Bitnami and it could be related to its configs.

Answer (score 0):

Elementor provides a tool to replace the URLs on your website. Follow the below steps:

1. Go to *Elementor > Tools > Replace URL* tab;
2. Enter your **old** and your **new** URLs and then click *Replace URL* button;
3. Under the *General tab > Regenerate CSS* click *Regenerate Files* button to make sure the URLs are refreshed throughout the site; also you may require to clear the cache of your site;
4. In *Settings > General* on your WordPress Dashboard, make sure that the URLs are similar.

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

I always use a tool like this one to change the site URL: https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB

What this does, is that it searches your complete database and changes every old url to the new one. You could do this manually using a query, but using this tool you make sure that serialized values won't break.